# How to debug Workflow Foundation with MEF using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019, workflow-foundation, designer

I have already read the documentation about WF here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/debugging-workflows

But I am unable to debug the workflow from Designer View loading the related assembly through MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework)

[image: MyWorkflowActivity in Designer View containing a breakpoint]

The associated assembly is correctly loaded containing the workflow xaml (due to build action "XamlAppDef") and is correctly initialized and executed using the below

```cs
 WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkflowNActivity(), param);
// [...]
wfApp.Run();
```

Also, breakpoints on custom Activities in **code-behind** do function as expected.

Any ideas on how to get the Workflow breakpoints to work in design mode?

**UPDATE**

An example solution can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/ole1986/TestWF

Below output is supposed to appear in Debug console

```
Hello World
```

Comment: Could you please [share a minimal, reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us?

Comment: Added an example on https://github.com/ole1986/TestWF

Comment: Ping Back: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1251591/breakpoints-do-not-work-in-workflow-foundation-des.html

Comment: Let me check the link:)

Comment: and, how is it going?

Comment: I think Microsoft has not added such feature. You should contact with them no doubt. I vote for your link.